# Writing a better jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, plugins

at the moment I have my jQuery plugin running it's logic in if statments.

For example I have:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myplugin = function(action) {

        if(action == "foo"){

        }

        if(action == "bar"){

        }

        if(action == "grapefruits"){            

        }

    }
})(jQuery);
```

Is there a better way to go about this?

Also the same with event handlers, can I declare them inside the plugin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can store different functions in an object and use an indexer, like this:

```
(function($) {
    var methods = {
        foo: function(action) { ... },
        bar: function(action, someParam) { ... },
        grapefruits: function(action, param1, param2) { ... },
        ...
    };

    $.fn.myplugin = function(action) {    
        methods[action].apply(this, arguments);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can i wrap a string with `$("....")` and add some functions can manipulate the string?

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to check the action multiple times, is there? YOu may as well use else if.I don't like the syntax for `switch` personally, and prefer this style. You can do it like

```
    if(action == "foo"){
    }
    else if(action == "bar"){
    }
    else if(action == "grapefruits"){            
    }
    else{
    //this is the default/unspecified case
    }
```

Another option is to store each as a name in an object. This is done in Python a lot too, for instance.

```
   var plugin_actions={
      'foo':function(){},
      'bar':function(){},
      'grapefruits':function(){}
       }
   plugin_actions[action]();
```

Comment: The second solution loses the `this` context and the parameters.  See my answer.