# The best way to write a jQuery plugin - If there is such a way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are quite a few ways to write plugins i.e. [here's a nice example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352077/writing-a-better-jquery-plugin/2352112#2352112) and what I've seen quite a lot of lately is the following code pattern and it's used by Doug Neiner [here](http://starter.pixelgraphics.us/);

```
(function($){
   $.formatLink = function(el, options){
    var base = this;
    base.$el = $(el);
    base.el = el;
    base.$el.data("formatLink", base);
    base.init = function(){
       base.options = $.extend({}, $.formatLink.defaultOptions, options); 
       //code here
    }                 
    base.init();
   };

   $.formatLink.defaultOptions = { };

   $.fn.formatLink = function(options){
      return this.each(function(){
       (new $.formatLink(this, options));
      });
   };
})(jQuery);
```

So, can anyone tell me the benefits of using the pattern above rather than the one below. I can't see the point in calling the $.extend function for every element in the jQuery stack (above), where the example below only does this once and then works on the stack.

To test it I created two plugins, using both patterns, which applied styles to about 5000 li elements and the code below took about 1 second whereas the pattern above took about 1.3 seconds.

```
(function($){
   $.fn.formatLink = function(options){
       var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.formatLink.defaultOptions, options || {});

       return this.each(function(){
        //code here
       });
    });

$.fn.formatLink.defaultOptions ={}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Have you looked at jQuery UI's Widget Factory? http://docs.jquery.com/UI_Developer_Guide#The_widget_factory

Comment: @Petersen - I took a quick look at that link but didn't really see how it was relative to what I asked? Is there something I'm missing? It talks about widget development. Could you please help me a little by telling me what I should be looking at.

Comment: Maybe he is referring to this section of the docs: http://docs.jquery.com/UI_Developer_Guide#Internal_functions_.26_scopes_explained

Comment: @Petersen & Fudgey - Thanks guys. It took a bit more reading but I got there in the end. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know Doug used this format when writing Anything Slider, I think it was done to expose internal functions and make it easier to call them after an addon has been initialized. For example in Anything Slider you can go to a particular slide two ways:

1. Use `$('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider(2);` which is intented for external links. But this method actually uses the method below to perform the action.
2. A second way, which shows how you can access the sub function through the data is done like this: `$('.anythingSlider').data('AnythingSlider').gotoPage(2);`

Maybe there are easier/better ways, but I would think the author has the best explaination/reasoning for this method. So @Doug Neiner (if that works), give us an idea :)

Comment: your absolutely right. I found this example on his site about custom events http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-custom-events-they-will-rock-your-world and after reading through his code I saw why he used the pattern he did. It made complete sense. I think the answer to my question is to use the plugin pattern which is most relative to the task I'm doing.

Comment: Also found this which is pretty helpful http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-plugin-design-patterns-part-i/